# how to consolidate aggregated calculated columns into one table

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have to calculate aggrgated columns for reporting and put all of them in one table. I have created a reference date table to compare the dates .

My source table looks like (mockd up data)

```
memberid    startdate     enddate
1          2017-05-23    2017-06-21
2          2017-05-01    2017-06-17 
3          2017-04-23    2017-05-28
4          2017-06-01    2017-07-21
5          2017-04-30    2017-05-27
```

I have to do weekly calculation  and this will be a cumulative kind of calculation in tableau. For example if I want to run the report on 2017-06-04, then I have to calculate  prior week data.
Each week should have below metrics.

```
1. how many members are new this week? count(Id's) where startdate >= 2017-05-28 
2. how many are discharged this week? count(Id's) where enddate=2017-05-27
3. how many are still in service? count(ID's) where startdate<=2017-05-28 and enddate >= 2017-05-28
```

I created aggregated calcs for #1 and #2 but unable to find #3.
Below calculations are done  for #1 and #2.
--newmembers

```
1.select  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, c.pkdate), CAST(c.pkdate AS DATE)) as weekdate,count(distinct memberid) as newmembers from #tempauth t
join [dbo].[Calendardays] c
on dateadd(dd,-7,dateadd(dd,-1,weekstart)) =DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, startdate), CAST(startdate AS DATE))
group by DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, c.pkdate), CAST(c.pkdate AS DATE))
```

--discharged

```
2.select  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, c.pkdate), CAST(c.pkdate AS DATE)) as weekdate,count(distinct memberid) as dischargedmembers from #tempauth t
join [dbo].[Calendardays] c
on dateadd(dd,-8,dateadd(dd,-1,weekstart)) =t.enddate
group by DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, c.pkdate), CAST(c.pkdate AS DATE))
```

Can anyone help me in finding out for members still in service(#3)? Also, I have to calculate these three calculation and put in single table for my reports. how can I do that?

Comment: What's the problem with query #3? I would recommend using a CTE (or a subquery) to get the relevant dates for the prior week (first date of prior wekk, last date, ...). Your outer query(s) can then rely on these dates without calculating them again and again.

Comment: I am not getting how to put everything in a single table .somehow my calculation is getting wrong.

Comment: You are cross joining table/view "Calendardays" with no restriction, which means you are joining all rows of Calendardays, I think that's not what you want. How does "Calendardays" look like?

Comment: calenderdays is just a reference table with only dates.. i basically have to calculate how many members are in service every week. if startdate<='this week' and enddate>='this week', how do i calculate this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the prior weeks' relevant dates (e. g. in a CTE) and return the results as subqueries:

```
with cte as
 (
   select distinct
          DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, pkdate) - 1), pkdate) as FirstDayOfWeek,
          DATEADD(DAY, 7 - (DATEPART(dw, pkdate)), pkdate) as LastDayOfWeek
     from dbo.Calendardays
    where pkdate <= dateadd(day, -8, getdate()) --> Calendardays until last week
 )
 select (select count(distinct memberid)
           from #tempauth t
           where t.StartDate >= cte.FirstDayOfWeek) as NewMembers,
        (select count(distinct memberid)
           from #tempauth t
          where ...)                                as DischargedMembers
        (select count(distinct memberid)
           from #tempauth t
          where ...)                                as MembersStillInService
      from cte;
```

Comment: If I create a stored procedure then I cannot connect this to tableau as it takes lot of time to execute. So instead thought of creating aggregated view and displaying the values from view.

Comment: What should be the date to be passed in stored procedure? I cannot give date parameter in tableau. My view should be displaying data starting from 1/1/2017 till latest week.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot.. this is what i am looking for to build a view.